# Why are we getting referrals from ratp.fr?

Tags: discussion, site-statistics

I was looking at the [Google Analytics data](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources)<sup>1</sup> for our site the other day, and I noticed something odd.

We have access to data on *referral traffic*. We [know](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/referral-traffic-google-analytics-53168.html) that:

> Referral traffic is Google's method of reporting visits that came to
>   your site from sources outside of its search engine. **When someone
>   clicks on a hyperlink to go to a new page on a different website,
>   Analytics tracks the click as a referral visit to the second site.** The
>   originating site is called a “referrer” because it refers traffic from
>   one place to the next. Referral traffic is one of three statistics
>   tracked by Google Analytics. The others are Search traffic -- visits
>   from a search engine -- and Direct traffic to a domain.

The top few referral sites are no surprise:

1. The top site is stackoverflow.com.
2. Next comes Reddit, with significantly fewer.
3. Then is superuser.com

No surprise here: people are most likely to click on an HNQ from SO or SU, and Reddit has many related/linked subreddits.

**The fourth referrer, however, is very strange**: [ratp.fr](http://ratp.fr/).

This site gives us nearly as many referrals as superuser.com (*as of the time I checked*), which is odd considering [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RATP_Group):

> The RATP Group (French: Groupe RATP), also known as the Régie Autonome
>   des Transports Parisiens (English: Autonomous Operator of Parisian
>   Transports) is a state-owned public transport operator headquartered
>   in Paris, France.

### Why is a French public transportation website responsible for so many referrals?

[image]

<sub><sup><sup>1</sup> link only available for 25K+ rep users</sup></sub>

Comment: @amaranth - Well, that's how I can see it, yes.

Comment: My guess is that it's coming through some kind of free wifi domain gateway provided by the transport network

Comment: @Valorum - Here is a screenshot from when I saw it. Its position went down.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - Where are the hand-drawn circles? How will we know what to look at?!

Comment: @Valorum - If you could erase the black bar and add a circle, that would be great.

Comment: @Valorum - Wow, the Meta site has analytics too.

Comment: http://www.zdnet.fr/actualites/wi-fi-4g-applis-la-ratp-veut-devenir-le-leader-de-la-mobilite-connectee-39827732.htm And http://www.batanga.com/comics/4747/las-10-mejores-armas-de-personajes-de-comics may be good clues

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Call me thick, but how does the second link relate?

Comment: @Valorum - The first picture comes from [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HVhSw.jpg), which is the SE imgur account. I doubt that counts as a referral, but it is possible, I suppose.

Comment: @Valorum Obie2 is correct. It's also on the list.

Comment: Never fear, the CMs (should be) here!

Comment: Ou est la gare?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I cannot provide any data but, given who the domain belongs to, this is likely to be an artefact of a WiFi network on French transit routes.

Apparently [some technical specific of their groundbreaking WiFi's login portal](http://www.zdnet.fr/actualites/wi-fi-4g-applis-la-ratp-veut-devenir-le-leader-de-la-mobilite-connectee-39827732.htm) redirects in such a way that their domain ends up as the HTTP Referer *[sic]* field when requests to Stack Exchange (and other sites) are made.

Comment: Should it worry me that a company that operates an underground train network company has wifi that's **groundbreaking**?

Comment: @Valorum: \*giggle\*

Comment: Hello Paris,  welcome to stackexchange!

Comment: Pffff, that's just awful and evil.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage: It's likely that les Parisiens have been on Stack Exchange from the beginning.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit quelle surprise.